# is it grammatical "from as the most perspectives as possible"

Tags: phrases

*He tries to consider things from **as the most perspectives as possible**.*

I would like to ask whether this sentence is grammatically OK? I try to express that the concerned guy does not jump to conclusions and considers all pros and cons of things. I want to apply the pattern of this type: come as fast as possible. But not sure if my sentence is appropriate.

Comment: I agree with Colin Fine's answer, and his point about it being awkward; but you will frequently hear native  speakers using **the most {plural noun}** to mean "as many {plural noun} as possible or available in this arrangement" or  **the most {singular noun}** to mean "the greatest degree of {singular noun}".  "This package gives you the most options." "This plan gives you the most flexibility."  Already embedded in  "the most {plural noun}" is the meaning "as many as possible", and so there's no need to "wrap" the locution with **as...as** as you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. The "as X Y as possible" pattern does not take a superlative for X.

What I think you mean is:

> from as many perspectives as possible

You can also say (though it's a bit more awkward)

> from the most perspectives possible

This is awkard mainly because "the most" nearly always introduces an adjective, as in "the most exciting adventure", so the reader is likely to get momentarily confused by it. But with a different superlative, such as

> the latest time possible

it's fine.